Python logger - configuration file problem
I have a logger.py configuration file, and I use it in many files in my Django project:
logger.py:
import datetime
import logging
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
LOGS_PATH = os.path.join(cwd, "logs")

if not os.path.isdir(LOGS_PATH):
    os.mkdir(LOGS_PATH)


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    LEVEL_COLOR_MAP = {
        logging.DEBUG: "\033[96m",  # Cyan
        logging.INFO: "\033[92m",  # Green
        logging.WARNING: "\033[93m",  # Yellow
        logging.ERROR: "\033[91m",  # Red
        logging.CRITICAL: "\033[95m",  # Magenta
    }

    def __init__(self, use_ansi=True, trim_module_name_and_time=False):
        self.use_ansi = use_ansi
        self.trim_module_name_and_time = trim_module_name_and_time

    def format(self, record):
        module_and_file_name = record.name
        func_name = record.funcName
        line_number = record.lineno
        module = f"[{module_and_file_name}.{func_name}:{line_number}]"

        if len(module) < 70:
            module = module + " " * (70 - len(module))

        level_name = record.levelname
        if len(level_name) < 7:
            level_name = level_name + " " * (7 - len(level_name))

        asctime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).strftime(
            "%b/%d %H:%M:%S"
        )

        if self.use_ansi:
            level_color = self.LEVEL_COLOR_MAP.get(record.levelno, "\033[97m")  # White

            if self.trim_module_name_and_time:
                log_message = f"{level_color}{level_name}\033[0m %(message)s" % {
                    "levelname": level_name,
                    "lineno": line_number,
                    "message": record.getMessage(),
                }
                return log_message
            else:
                log_message = (
                    f"{module} [{asctime}] {level_color}{level_name}\033[0m %(message)s"
                    % {
                        "module": module,
                        "levelname": level_name,
                        "lineno": line_number,
                        "message": record.getMessage(),
                    }
                )
                return log_message
        else:
            if self.trim_module_name_and_time:
                log_message = f"{level_name}  %(message)s" % {
                    "levelname": level_name,
                    "lineno": line_number,
                    "message": record.getMessage(),
                }
                return log_message
            else:
                log_message = f"{module} [{asctime}] {level_name}  %(message)s" % {
                    "module": module,
                    "levelname": level_name,
                    "lineno": line_number,
                    "message": record.getMessage(),
                }
                return log_message


logger_config = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "custom_formatter": {"()": CustomFormatter, "use_ansi": False},
        "custom_formatter_simple": {
            "()": CustomFormatter,
            "use_ansi": True,
            "trim_module_name_and_time": True,
        },
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(lineno)s [%(levelname)-7s] %(message)s [IP: {REMOTE_ADDR}]",
            "datefmt": "%b/%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
        "simple": {"format": "%(levelname)s %(message)s"},
    },
    "handlers": {
        "null": {
            "class": "logging.NullHandler",
        },
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "custom_formatter_simple",
            # "level": "DEBUG",
        },
        "file_debug": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "filename": os.path.join(LOGS_PATH, "log_debug.log"),
            "backupCount": 9,  # keep at most 9 log files
            "maxBytes": 52428800,  # 50*1024*1024 bytes (50MB)
            "formatter": "custom_formatter",
            # "level": "DEBUG",
        },
        "file_info": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "filename": os.path.join(LOGS_PATH, "log_info.log"),
            "backupCount": 9,
            "maxBytes": 52428800,
            "formatter": "custom_formatter",
            # "level": "INFO",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": ["file_debug", "file_info", "console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        }
    },
}

E.g. views.py:
import logging
from utils.logger import logger_config
logging.config.dictConfig(logger_config)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info(f"Logger {__name__} initialized.")

Right now I want to redirect these logs:
Not Found: /wrong_url
WARNING Not Found: /wrong_url
[30/Aug/2024 07:32:16] "GET /wrong_url HTTP/1.1" 404 5380

so they should be stored only in the django_debug.log.
I thought, that when I add logger and specify to save it in the debug file, then it'll be fine:
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": ["file_debug", "file_info", "console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["file_debug"],
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },

But it doesn't work.
Could you point out what's wrong? What's the reason why I can still see the warnings in the console and in the django_info.log file, even when I set it to only log to the debug file?
Thank you in advance for your response.

I guess you are see django.server logs in the console (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#django-server). You need to override django.server logger too.
"loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": ["file_debug", "file_info", "console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["file_debug"],
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.server": {
            "handlers": ["file_debug"],
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },

Also you can see the name of the logger using name argument in the formatter settings. If you change your "console" handler to use "verbose" formatter, you will see, which logger send message to the console

I've done this as well. The effect is the same. There must be something wrong with the configuration.
